# Redux Form action undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

I am trying to do authorization.
I get the data from reduxForm, and it is visible, but for some reason the data does not immediately get into the function, but goes to action, and I get an undefined value.
Registration is carried out on the same principle, but there are no errors.

Where could my mistake be?

```js
REDUX

const NewUserEror = "NewUserEror";
const RegSucces = "RegSucces";
const RegStart = "RegStart";
const RegEnd = "RegEnd";

let initialState = {
  error: null,
  loading: false
};

const registrationReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RegSucces:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: false
      };
    case NewUserEror:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload
      };
    case RegStart:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case RegEnd:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export const LogInUser = data => async (
  dispatch,
  getState,
  { getFirebase }
) => {
  const firebase = getFirebase();
  dispatch({ type: RegStart });
  try {
    await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password);
    dispatch({ type: RegSucces });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({ type: NewUserEror, payload: err.message });
  }
  dispatch({ type: RegEnd });
};


CONTAINER

import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Login from "./login";
import LogInUser from "./../../../redux/registrationReducer"
class AuthBox extends React.Component{

  Userlogin=(formdata)=>{

    this.props.LogInUser(formdata)
  }
  render(){
    return<Login {...this.props} Userlogin={this.Userlogin}></Login>
  }
}

let mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
  return{
  loading:state.Regis.loading,
  error:state.Regis.error
  }
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps,{LogInUser})(AuthBox);



COMPONENT

const Login = props => {
  let onSubmit = formData => {
  props.Userlogin(formData);
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.formbox}>
      <div className={classes.form}>
        <h5 className={classes.formtitle}>Вход</h5>
        <LoginForm onSubmit={onSubmit}></LoginForm>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKxat.png)

[Action undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO8mg.png)

p.s sorry for my english

Comment: Could you split up the code into files like you have? One thing that's not clear to me is that you are doing a named export with `export const LogInUser ...`, but in your container you're doing a _default_ import with `import LogInUser from "...";`, which won't work. Not sure if that relates to your issue.

Comment: @Jacob You were right, THANKS !.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NON DEFAULT EXPORT MUST BE IN {}**

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Login from "./login";

////// here
import {LogInUser} from "./../../../redux/registrationReducer"
////

class AuthBox extends React.Component{

  Userlogin=(formdata)=>{

    this.props.LogInUser(formdata)
  }
  render(){
    return<Login {...this.props} Userlogin={this.Userlogin}></Login>
  }
}

let mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
  return{
  loading:state.Regis.loading,
  error:state.Regis.error
  }
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps,{LogInUser})(AuthBox);
```